# Stack Exchange iOS App is giving me errors

Tags: discussion, support, login, ios-app

I have been using the Stack Exchange iOS app for years.  Today, for the first time, I was unable to comment or ask using it for Ask Different.  It suggested that I log out and back in.  When I did that (I use an FB login), the FB login page told me that the FB login for that app was made "inactive" and that the developers of the "FB app" were made aware of the issue.  I then looked to see if there was an update available for the app, and discovered that the app was no longer on the app store.

Wow, I don't know how long this has been the case.  Anyone know if it's possible to get it working again, or should I not bother?  What do other people do to access Stack on their iPhones?

Comment: For latecomers to this thread - TL:DR the iOS app is now dead. The final functionality was switched off over Xmas 2022 & now it fails to display any data at all.

Answer (score 3):

The app is no longer workable IMO as they are pulling the plug on the back end API. I can't speak for FB login, however and I hope someone can test that for you.

- [Mobile app infrastructure being decommissioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383026/mobile-app-infrastructure-being-decommissioned)

For most use cases, the mobile web view may be the best you get unless you can use the full app on Mobile Safari or your browser of choice on iOS.

In some cases, valuable API are likely to get renamed as SE Developers roll back the feeds and functions and also stop developing the apps with updates. There's a ton to love about a native app like push notifications, layout, lack of browser chrome, so this will be a painful transition for many I am sure.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the 'sign in with Stack Exchange' still works. tbh, mine never asks me to re-login like the web pages do periodically. Voting or replying to posts is no longer working, but you can read posts/questions.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin I'll soften my not working at all to I don't recommend it. I appreciate the quick correction on this.

Comment: It's a great shame, imnsho. I know it was below par really, but while it worked it was my way of checking in when I am on the road. I can't handle it in a browser from a phone, there's too much 'periphery to data' ratio.

Comment: I stopped checking Stack Exchange while on the go once I lost access to the app due to getting a new phone and being unable to redownload the app.

Answer (score 2):

Stack Exchange mobile apps are no longer in development and therefore their functionalities are gradually declining. The Stack Exchange recommends using a mobile browser to access any Stack Exchange site from a smart phone. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/348076/650706) from Meta Stack Exchange for more details.

Personally, I continue to use the iOS app only to see the new questions or answers and any changes to them. I just tap on Share and choose Open in Safari if I decide to write an answer or make an edit.