# Where should I report? iOS Stack Exchange app not allowing Google login

Tags: support, bug, ios-app

The stack exchange ios app is failing in the google login flow after it returns from Google web flow.
[image]

Where’s the right place to report this?

Answer (score 0):

The iOS app is no longer supported, see [Stack Exchange iOS App is giving me errors](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4136/stack-exchange-ios-app-is-giving-me-errors). Alternatively, you can just use any mobile browser to access AD (and the other SE sites).

Comment: Another option is using the [Crew for Exchange](https://apps.apple.com/it/app/crew-for-exchange/id1547171709?l=en&platform=iphone) app. This can even be installed on Macs running macOS 12 with Apple M1 (or later) chips. Although I'm not sure why you'd do that on a Mac anyway, since browsers do the job just fine.